# "App.Current.myProperty" does not work, but "((app)Application.Current).myProperty" does

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I have my own public property in App object. But it doesn't work while I trying to access it via `App.Current.myProperty`. it work only via `((app)Application.Current).myProperty`.
I see a lot samples where people use `App.Current` to access own properties. Did I missed something? Override `Current` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should add your own `Current` property into your `App` class.

That's because it by default `Application.Current` returns `Application` class instance, not your derived class.

Comment: public new static App Current 
{
 get
 {
  return (App)Application.Current;
 }
}  Like this?